# Return maximum value after K swaps using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am attempting following problem from geeks for geeks, problem link; [enter link description here][1]

Here is my python code to solve it;

```
def swap_kdigits(s, k, maximum):
    if k == 0:
       return
    for i in range(0, len(s) - 1): 
   /* find maximum element on the right */
       maxc = s[i]
       for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):
          if int(s[j]) > int(maxc):
            maxc = s[j]

       if maxc != s[i]:
         idx = s.index(maxc)
         ll = list(s)
        # do the swap
         ll[i], ll[idx] = ll[idx], ll[i]
         s = ''.join(ll)
         maximum = max(int(s), maximum) /* update maximum values*/
        # make  a recursive call on the new string
         swap_kdigits(s, k - 1, maximum)
        # backtrack
         ll[i], ll[idx] = ll[idx], ll[i]

         s = ''.join(ll)


def main_fn(s, k):
    maximum = int(s) /*initialize maximum variable*/
    return swap_kdigits(s, k, maximum) /* call helper function */
```

Can I please get some help on how to return the `maximum` value obtained to the calling function? As you can see, right now nothing is been returned. Help is appreciated.
[1]: [https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/largest-number-in-k-swaps-1587115620/1/?page=2&category[]=Strings&sortBy=submissions](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/largest-number-in-k-swaps-1587115620/1/?page=2&category%5B%5D=Strings&sortBy=submissions)

**Edited Code Without Recursion**

```
def swap_kdigits(s, k):
# define current max
   maximum = int(s)

   for i in range(0, len(s) - 1):
      maxc = s[i]
      if k == 0:
        break
      for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):

         if int(s[j]) > int(maxc):
            maxc = s[j]
   

      if maxc != s[i]:
        k -= 1
        idx = s[i + 1:].rfind(maxc) + i + 1  # find last occurrence
        ll = list(s)
        # do the swap
        ll[i], ll[idx] = ll[idx], ll[i]
        s = ''.join(ll)
        # find the new max
        maximum = max(int(s), maximum)
       
  return maximum
```

Comment: Are you interested also in a non-recursive solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have a GeeksForGeeks account, I cannot login into the site and see for myself if there's an actual answer to this question. I'm telling this, because I don't know why you came up with a recursive function for the solution.

After testing your script and making some modifications, I realized your script should work without any recursion. That's right, you made a procedural solution. But why it's not working?

**Reason 1)** Where is the string `s` being updated? From what I saw, you are updating the sequence `s` on this line: `ll[i], ll[idx] = ll[idx], ll[i]`. That's ok, but note this doesn't need any recursion. There's no point in calling `swap_kdigits` again from the for-loop.

`strings` in python are immutable objects. Unless you return the string sequence from a `swap_kdigits` call, you're never really updating the string `s` on any deeper levels of recursive calls. You are only modifying it on the root level, and again, never returning anything. That's why your script returns nothing.

**Reason 2)** If recursive calls are pointless here, where should you use `k`? My guess is whenever a swap is made towards the final maximum sequence.

**Reason 3)** About this line: `maximum = max(int(s), maximum)`. Sure, it makes sense. You're always walking towards the maximum value. But will `int(s)` be always higher than `maximum`?

As a short answer: I don't know, didn't tested it so far... So in order to contain possible errors with the script, I've placed a safeguard using your backtracking line in the script below.

**Reason 4)** On this line: `idx = s.index(maxc)`, this line should be `idx = s[i + 1:].index(maxc) + i + 1`. Confusing? I bet, but it makes sense: on the for-loop you're seeking the `maxc` on the sequence after index `i`. So, when seeking the index of `maxc`, you should pass only the subset where `maxc` is present, not the whole string.

If you didn't do this, your script would give you a wrong result when testing on this sequence: `"3435335"`. The reason are the repeated characters.

Finally, here's the working version of your script. It's not recursive anymore because as I explained before, it never needed recursion the way it was written.

```
def swap_kdigits(s, k, maximum):
    # Iterate over every character of the sequence, except the last character
    for i in range(0, len(s) - 1): 
        maxc = s[i]

        # If the k number of swaps are exceeded, stop the algorithm
        if (k == 0):
            break

        # Find the maximum character on the subset s[i+1:]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):
            if int(s[j]) > int(maxc):
                maxc = s[j]

        if maxc != s[i]:
            # Remember the for-loop with j?
            # We are not seeking the maxc in the entire string,
            # only in the subset starting from index: i+1
            idx = s[i + 1:].index(maxc) + i + 1
            ll = list(s)

            # Swap character to obtain a new maximum sequence
            ll[i], ll[idx] = ll[idx], ll[i]
            s = ''.join(ll)
            
            # This is a safe guard.
            #
            # In the examples provided by the GeeksForGeeks, the
            # else block is never executed.
            #
            # However, what if int(s) is not really the maximum
            # number?
            #
            # Then, we make a backtrack to return to the previous
            # maximum sequence.
            if (int(s) > maximum):
                # Edit: update maximum number
                maximum = int(s)

                # Made a swap, decrease k
                k -= 1
            else:
                # Go back to the previous sequence
                ll[i], ll[idx] = ll[idx], ll[i]
                s = ''.join(ll)


    # Return the maximum sequence
    return s


def main_fn(s, k):
    maximum = int(s)
    return swap_kdigits(s, k, maximum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main_fn("3435335", 3))
```

I'm editing this answer to show you how I would make a recursive solution to this example:

```
def rec_swap(seq, k, offset=0):
    # Check if the number of swaps is still valid, or
    # if the offset has reached the end of the sequence
    if (k > 0 and offset < (len(seq)-1)):

        # Select maxc from a subset of right characters
        subset = seq[offset:]

        # Find the max character on the subset
        maxc = max(list(subset), key=lambda c: int(c))

        # Find the index of maxc on the subset
        maxi = subset.index(maxc)

        # Transform maxi to relate to the whole sequence seq
        maxi += offset

        # Cannot swap same character
        if (maxi != offset):
            # Create a previous of the swapped sequence
            # swapped = swap(seq, offset, maxi)
            #
            # Using this print we can see how many iterations it took
            # to find the maximum sequence. It might be less than k.
            print('SWAP: ', seq[offset], seq[maxi])
            swapped = seq[:offset] + seq[maxi] + seq[offset+1:maxi] + seq[offset] + seq[maxi+1:]

            # Only go deep if next sequence is higher than current one
            if (int(swapped) > int(seq)):
                # Return deepest, or maximum, sequence possible:
                #
                # As we made a swap on this recursion level, k is decreased by -1
                # As we move one character to the right, offset is increased by 1
                return rec_swap(swapped, k-1, offset+1)
    
    # If there's nothing to do, return current sequence
    return seq

def main():
    result = rec_swap("3435335", 3)
    print('RESULT: ', result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this recursive example, you can see I do not rely on altering the sequence  `seq` as if passed by reference. I simply return `seq` at the end of the recursive call, or when I go down one level. This allows me to always return the deepest recursion sequence.

As strings in python are immutable data, there's no need for backtracking.

Also, instead of making a for-loop to find `maxc`, I used the built-in function `max(target, key)`, using a lambda on the key paramter to iterate over the list, and find the max character (when converted to an int).

I left this line on purpose `print('SWAP: ', seq[offset], seq[maxi])`. When the recursive function is called, this print shows the actual number of swap operations made to the sequence `seq`.

Output of recursive script:

```
SWAP:  3 5
SWAP:  4 5
SWAP:  3 4
RESULT:  5543333
```

Comment: Appreciate your thoughts and useful feedback. In the solution that you proposed, are we supposed to change `maximum` or not? It seems, right now it is stuck at the value of original string.

Comment: Actually, I don't know wether you need `maximum` variable at all. This is an implicit topic I mention in **reason 3)**, as I have no idea if we need to backtrack to previous results, or if `int(s)` will be always higher than `maximum` or not. To all examples I've tested so far, the `else` clause was never executed.

Comment: If you want to build a safeguard in case `int(s) < maximum`, then yes, you should assign a new value to `maximum` at the block where you decrease `k`. Otherwise, I think `maximum` variable is not needed on this algorithm.

Comment: Note that, as `swap_kdigits` is not recursive anymore, you don't need to pass an initial state of `maximum` from `main_fn`. You can initialize `maximum` before the for-loop starts inside `swap_kdigits`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why in your code `k` is being decreased only after checking for maximum. I did post a new code, plz see non-recursive code above. I was wondering why can't we decrease `k` right after checking whether `maxc` is not same as `s[i]`. kindly advise

Comment: On the GeeksForGeeks link, it's stated that `k` is the number of swaps available. If you pass `k as 2` or `k as 1`, `swap_kdigits` does not return the maximum number that the string `s` can generate. It returns the maximum number based on a single swap, or two character swaps.

Comment: That's why when you made a recursive call, you passed `k - 1`. You were inattentively telling the application to make `k` recursive calls of `swap_kdigits` and then stop when `k` reached 0. But as the recursion is gone, I decrease `k` whenever a swap is made on the for-loop, which is when `int(s) > maximum`.

Comment: In your example, you nailed it. `k` should be decreased whenever a swap is made on the sequence `s`.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a recursive solution, just to show how I'd do it using recursion.

Comment: As recursion is another form of loop, it substitutes the first for-loop from the procedural script. That's why when `k` equals zero, or when `offset` reaches the last character of the sequence `seq`, the recursion (or iteration) should stop.